# Execute Python file as linux command

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

I have a file named command1.py and it is available to the system path. That means i can type **python command1.py** from anywhere in the system and it will execute the file. but i want ti execute this file as a linux command.

eg, i want that file to execute when i type **command1** in terminal

i have few lame solutions like creating an alias or creating a symlink but i do not want to do like that. Is there any way i can defind a unix command for that file and execute from the terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. You put a hashbang comment at the top and chmod+x the file

Comment: @pvg tried that not working. Did you understand my question?

Comment: I understand your question. 'it's not working' is not very clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python does not allow additional comment with env python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329841/python-does-not-allow-additional-comment-with-env-python)

Comment: There is nothing in this question so far that suggests what you've linked is a duplicate, @e4c5

Comment: The use of shebang @pvg (unfortunate title yes, but the answers are duplicates)

Comment: @e4c5 that's someone screwing up the shebang. If you want to link something that's strictly about how to write and use the shebang, maybe. But you don't know the poster's made this fairly specific mistake at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Have you put a suitable `#!` at the start of the file, made it executable, and installed it to a location on `$PATH`?  There's nothing to suggest you've done any of those things.

Answer (score 2):

command1.py

1. in terminal, type "where python", you will get eg.
   “/usr/bin/python” copy it
2. vi command1.py on the top type "#!/usr/bin/python" save it.
3. mv command1.py command1
4. you can type command1 in terminal and execute

Answer (score -1):

Put the absolute path of `python` in your script, just like starting a bash script. Something like below:

```
       #!/usr/bin/python
```

Depending on installation you path might be different. And make sure it's executable, `chmod +x scriptname.py`